# Можно ли отключить передачу заголовков Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site в запросе из браузера при обращении к url на другом домене?

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, browsers, http-заголовки

Можно ли отключить передачу заголовков Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site в запросе из браузера при обращении к url на другом домене.

То есть предположим есть domen1 и domen2 оба сайта мои и есть возможность добавлять на них JS,HTML теги и заголовки ответа сервера. Можно ли что то сделать на первом или втором сайте чтобы браузер перестал передавать эти заголовки в запросе?

P.S. для решения какой то конкретной задачи сейчас эта информация использована не будет. Интересуюсь для общего развития и с целью пополнения багажа знаний по Web-безопасности.